Не работает встроенный микрофон ноутбук lenovo ideapad 330-15IKB, Ubuntu 24.04
У меня был windows и встроенный микрофон работал корректно. Поменял на ubuntu 24.04, и встроенный микрофон не работает. Система его видит, но когда я говорю - он не слышит. Проверял - микрофон включен, усиливал сигнал на максимум - не распознает. Нужна помощь всё уже облазил - заранее благодарю.

Установите pavucontrol и посмотрите что происходит в нём

Идентичная проблема. Тот же ноутбук, тоже сидел на винде и звук был, а как перешел на Ubuntu 24.04 микрофон пропал. Удалось что-то узнать?
